# Get user from Windows login in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have an internal website and I need to see who is logged onto the Windows PC so that they don't need to type their name themselves.

I have tried:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
```

and

```
string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

It works on my computer but when I use it on the server it doesn't.

Comment: What authentication mode are you using to identify the user?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx

Comment: i have added 
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" /> and its stil not working

Comment: Please paste the code for getting Principal and IIS setting for Authentication Methods

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should take care of:

1. in the web.config: `
2. To get the current user, use this: `System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;`

if you needed anything more plz ask

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
<system.web>
  <anonymousIdentification enabled="false"/>
</system.web>
```

I can get user very simple like this:

```
HttpContext.User
```